# Adding 2 Hashmaps to a single document in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have uploaded 1 Hashmap to firestore.And when i try to upload one more Hashmap to the same document it replaces my previous Hashmap.Why is it so?

I change the String title everytime and still it replaces the previous Hashmap.

```
        String poll1 = Poll1.getText().toString().trim();
        String poll2 = Poll2.getText().toString().trim();
        String poll3 = Poll3.getText().toString().trim();
        String title = Title.getText().toString().trim();



        DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.collection("Polls").document("abc1");

        Map<String, Object> nestedData = new HashMap<>();
        nestedData.put(poll1 , 0 );
        nestedData.put(poll2 , 0);
        nestedData.put(poll3 , 0);

        Map<String, Object> upload = new HashMap<>();
        upload.put(title, nestedData);

        documentReference.set(upload).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(polls.this, "UPLOADED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(polls.this, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your document needs to mention that this has to be merged instead replace.

```
.set(data, SetOptions.merge())
```

Try this if it works.

```
documentReference.set(upload, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast.makeText(polls.this, "UPLOADED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(polls.this, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```